# How to simulate while loop in Jinja2

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, jinja2

How would I do the following in jinja2:

```
while apples < oranges:
    # some work here.
```

According to http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/extensions/#loop-controls, and by the error I am getting, Jinja2 does not support while loops.

The question is I want to continuously do some work as long as the value of `apples` is less than that of `oranges`

Thanks for any help.

Also something equivalent to `while True:` is good also.

Comment: I didn't even know jinja2 had variables that could change values in a way that would make that make sense. Why are you putting business logic in a template anyway?

Answer (score 9):

To loop in Jina2 you have to use : for. To end the loop in the for block you can use break. 
See : http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/#loop-controls.

```
jinja_env = Environment(extensions=['jinja2.ext.loopcontrols'])
```

An "endless" loop you can create with:

```
{% for _ in range(1, large_number) %}

   {% if loop.index > stop_at %}{% break %}{% endif %} 

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @vocausa seem to be you can't use break anymore, and I'm actually puzzled how to write something like this without break??

Comment: using something like `{% for user in users if not user.hidden %}`

from the [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/)

Comment: @muttonchops i don't understand this statement in my case it's useless. I need to go through all i team and if found break a loop, if not continue looping. I don't need any exclusions..